# Win32/C: Convert line endings to DOS/Windows format

Tags: c, windows, string, replace, line-endings

I've the following C function in a Windows API project that reads a file and based on the line endings (UNIX, MAC, DOS) it replaces the line endings with the right line-endings for Windows (`\r\n`):

```
// Standard C header needed for string functions
#include <string.h>

// Defines for line-ending conversion function
#define LESTATUS INT 
#define LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED (0)
#define LE_CHANGES_SUCCEEDED (1)
#define LE_CHANGES_FAILED   (-1)

/// <summary>
/// If the line endings in a block of data loaded from a file contain UNIX (\n) or MAC (\r) line endings, this function replaces it with DOS (\r\n) endings.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inData">An array of bytes of input data.</param>
/// <param name="inLen">The size, in bytes, of inData.</param>
/// <param name="outData">An array of bytes to be populated with output data.  This array must already be allocated</param>
/// <param name="outLen">The maximum number of bytes that can be stored in outData.</param>
/// <param name="bytesWritten">A pointer to an integer that receives the number of bytes written into outData.</param>
/// <returns>
/// If no changes were necessary (the file already contains \r\n line endings), then the return value is LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED.<br/>
/// If changes were necessary, and it was possible to store the entire output buffer, the return value is LE_CHANGES_SUCCEEDED.<br/>
/// If changes were necessary but the output buffer was too small, the return value is LE_CHANGES_FAILED.<br/>
/// </returns>
LESTATUS ConvertLineEndings(BYTE* inData, INT inLen, BYTE* outData, INT outLen, INT* bytesWritten)
{
    char *posR = strstr(inData, "\r");
    char *posN = strstr(inData, "\n");
    // Case 1: the file already contains DOS/Windows line endings.
    // So, copy the input array into the output array as-is (if we can)
    // Report an error if the output array is too small to hold the input array; report success otherwise.
    if (posN != NULL && posR != NULL)
    {
        if (outLen >= inLen)
        {
            strcpy(outData, inData);
            return LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED;
        }
        return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
    }
    // Case 2: the file contains UNIX line endings.
    else if (posN != NULL && posR == NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int track = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < inLen; i++)
        {
            if (inData[i] != '\n')
            {
                outData[track] = inData[i];
                track++;
                if (track>outLen) return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
            }
            else
            {
                outData[track] = '\r';
                track++;
                if (track > outLen) return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
                outData[track] = '\n';
                track++;
                if (track > outLen) return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
            }
            *bytesWritten = track;
        }
    }
    // Case 3: the file contains Mac-style line endings.
    else if (posN == NULL && posR != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int track = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < inLen; i++)
        {
            if (inData[i] != '\r')
            {
                outData[track] = inData[i];
                track++;
                if (track>outLen) return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
            }
            else
            {
                outData[track] = '\r';
                track++;
                if (track > outLen) return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
                outData[track] = '\n';
                track++;
                if (track > outLen) return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
            }
            *bytesWritten = track;
        }
    }
    return LE_CHANGES_SUCCEEDED;
}
```

However, I feel like this function is *very* long (almost 70 lines) and could be reduced somehow. I've searched on Google but couldn't find anything useful; is there any function in either the C library or the Windows API that will allow me to perform a string-replace rather than manually searching the string byte-by-byte in O(n) time?

Comment: What would that function do different from what you are doing now?

Comment: The best search functions run in O(n/k) time, where k is the length of the substring being found.  You're looking for a single character...

Comment: @Jongware perhaps use some standard library or winapi function instead of searching the array manually, to reduce length and make it easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every character needs looking at *precisely* one time, not more and not less. The very first line of your code already makes repeated comparisons, as both `strstr` calls start at the same position. You could have used something like

```
char *posR = strstr(inData, "\r");
if (posR && posR[1] == '\n')
   // Case 1: the file already contains DOS/Windows line endings.
```

and if this fails, continue from where you ended if you did find an `\r` or, if `posR == NULL`, starting from the top again. But then you made the `strstr` already "look at" every character until the end!

Two additional notes:

1. there was no need for `strstr` because you are looking for a single character; use `strchr` next time;
2. the `strXXX` functions all assume your input is a properly formed C string: it should end with a terminating `0`. However, you already provide the length in `inLen`, so you don't *have* to check for zeroes. If there may or may not be a `0` in your input before `inLen` bytes, you need to take appropriate action. Based on the purpose of this function, I'm assuming you don't need to check for zeroes at all.

My proposal: look at every character from the start *once*, and only take action when it is *either* an `\r` *or* an `\n`. If the first of these you encounter is an `\r` *and* the next one is an `\n`, you're done. (This assumes the line endings are not "mixed".)

If you do not return in this first loop, there is something else than `\r\n`, and you can continue from that point on. But you still only have to act on *either* an `\r` *or* `\n`! So I propose this shorter code (and an `enum` instead of your defines):

```
enum LEStatus_e { LE_CHANGES_FAILED=-1, LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED, LE_CHANGES_SUCCEEDED };

enum LEStatus_e ConvertLineEndings(BYTE *inData, INT inLen, BYTE *outData, INT outLen, INT *bytesWritten)
{
    INT sourceIndex = 0, destIndex;

    if (outLen < inLen)
        return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;

    /*  Find first occurrence of either \r or \n
        This will return immediately for No Change Needed */
    while (sourceIndex < inLen)
    {
        if (inData[sourceIndex] == '\r')
        {
            if (sourceIndex < inLen-1 && inData[sourceIndex+1] == '\n')
            {
                memcpy (outData, inData, inLen);
                *bytesWritten = inLen;
                return LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (inData[sourceIndex] == '\n')
            break;
        sourceIndex++;
    }
    /* We processed this far already: */
    memcpy (outData, inData, sourceIndex);
    if (sourceIndex == inLen)
        return LE_NO_CHANGES_NEEDED;
    destIndex = sourceIndex;

    while (sourceIndex < inLen)
    {
        switch (inData[sourceIndex])
        {
            case '\n':
            case '\r':
                sourceIndex++;
                if (destIndex+2 >= outLen)
                    return LE_CHANGES_FAILED;
                outData[destIndex++] = '\r';
                outData[destIndex++] = '\n';
                break;
            default:
                outData[destIndex++] = inData[sourceIndex++];
        }
    }
    *bytesWritten = destIndex;
    return LE_CHANGES_SUCCEEDED;
}
```

There are a few old and rare 'plain text' formats that use other constructions; from memory, something like `\r\n\n`. If you want to be able to sanitize *anything*, you can add a skip for all `\r`s after a single `\n`, and the same for the opposite case. This will also clean up any "mixed" line endings, as it will correctly treat `\r\n` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would consider a somewhat simpler code, half as many lines.  Of course, as Ben Voigt pointed out, you can't beat O(n) time, so I made no attempt to do so.  I didn't use any library functions, because it seems simpler this way, and I doubt that extra function calls could make the code faster.

```
enum lestatus {
  le_no_changes_needed = 0,
  le_changes_succeeded = 1,
  le_changes_failed = -1
};

enum lestatus ConvertLineEndings(char *indata, int inlen,
                                 char *outdata, int outlen)
{
  int outpos = 0, inpos;
  enum lestatus it_changed = le_no_changes_needed;
  for (inpos = 0; inpos<inlen;inpos++) {
    if (outpos + 1 > outlen) return le_changes_failed;
    if (indata[inpos] != '\r' && indata[inpos] != '\n') {
      /* it is an ordinary character, just copy it */
      outdata[outpos++] = indata[inpos];
    } else if (outpos + 2 > outlen) {
      return le_changes_failed;
    } else if ((indata[inpos+1] == '\r' || indata[inpos+1] == '\n')
               && indata[inpos] != indata[inpos+1]) {
      /* it is \r\n or \n\r, output it in canonical order */
      outdata[outpos++] = '\r';
      outdata[outpos++] = '\n';
      inpos++; /* skip the second character */
    } else {
      /* it is a mac or unix line ending, convert to dos */
      outdata[outpos++] = '\r';
      outdata[outpos++] = '\n';
      it_changed = le_changes_succeeded;
    }
  }
  return it_changed;
}
```

The biggest differences in my code are that

1. I used the increment operator.
2. I avoided library functions for simplicity.
3. My function handles mixed-ending files correctly (in my interpretation).
4. I prefer lowercase characters.  This is obviously a stylistic preference.
5. I prefer an enum over #defines.  Also a stylistic preference.