# Unix text file to Windows text file using C with mks temp

Tags: c

I want to implement a clean code using C that converts text file from a standard to other. That's how it works: I need to create a temporary file using mks temp function so that i can deal with the temp file. So I would open the file with fdopen and at the end of each line, i need to exchance from "\n" to "\r\n".

Any idea or code snipet so that I can understan how to make that work? How to read any line? And how to make the original file to be a windows file if i am dealing with the temp file?

Txs a lot!

Comment: You may find this question I asked a while ago useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540607/win32-c-convert-line-endings-to-dos-windows-format

Comment: Time to start reading your C textbook.